# Do an action only if a condition is met in all iterations of a loop

Tags: c#, for-loop

Is there a way to only trigger an action when a condition is met in **all** iterations of a `for` loop?

Example:

```
if ((i % 1 == 0) && (i % 2 == 0) && (...) && (i % 20 == 0))
{
    Do action x
}
```

This is what I tried, but it didn't work as expected:

```
for (int b=1; b<21; b++)
{
    if (i % b == 0)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want t get a number that is a multiple of all numbers up from 1 to 20?

Comment: For loops don't return anything.  Do you mean when all conditions inside a for loop are correct?

Comment: To start, you could omit all non-prime numbers, because those are redundant anyhow.

Comment: @Bernhard missing out composites with repeated factors changes the result, e.g. OP code requires 16 and 9 to be factors of i but neither are prime. You could just test for i%232792560 but that's not the question.

Comment: I recommend reading through [these questions](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=euler+5+is%3Aquestion)

Comment: @Pete My bad, I was too quick. I am not sure if your suggestion really doesn't answer the question though. It may actually be what the OP should use

Comment: Can anyone explain the number of upvotes?

Comment: I ask the same @oarfish

Comment: @oarfish Some arbitrary algorithm selected this as a "Hot Network Question", so it gets highlighted in the sidebar across the entire Stack Exchange network, advertising it to readers everywhere on SO and from all other SE sites - who might not be very good judges of question quality on _our_ site. To be clear, I'm not saying it's a _bad_ question specifically, albeit vaguely phrased - but it's definitely not a +22 question either.

Comment: It's a very simple question but I often come across simple things like this that I don't know how to solve; After all everything I learned was selftaught online :)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

There is classic solution:

```
var flag = true;
for(int b = 2; b < 21; b++)
{
     if (i % b != 0)
     {
         flag = false;
         break;
     }
}
if(flag)
   SomeAction():
```

At first we assume, that all conditions(loops) are met: `var flag = true`.
If at least one condition is not met: `if (i % b != 0)`, we stop looping process: `break;` because there is no need to continue checking, and set `flag = false`, now via `flag` variable we know the result of our checking and can use it later to determine should we call `SomeAction()` or not.

Comment: You could start looping from b = 2

Comment: @MooingDuck I saw that and thought "Surely you can do that in C# too".  Nope :(  You can do that in C# if you break it into 2 lines `int[] x = {2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 17, 19}; foreach(int i in x) { ... }`

Comment: I tried something like that but I guess I had the syntax wrong, that way works.

Comment: -1 this is the worst answer here, not sure why it was accepted.  If you're adverse to LINQ, at the very _least_ extract this to a method...

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Where the asker has come up with an almost-solution, showing them how to make their solution work is far more valuable than just saying "scrap that and replace it with this one line of LINQ".

Comment: I accepted this as the answer because it was exactly what I was looking for :D @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft When Googlers come here in the future, they probably aren't all using C#. I upvoted this and the LINQ answer, but context matters.

Comment: @Rawling and others: please read my comment again.  My complaint was not about LINQ, it was that this should be extracted to a method.  This is poorly written code in any language.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Sorry didn't see that. This absolutely should be extracted to a method. But I think showing how this could be accomplished in *any* language is the important part. Barry's answer is C# specific, which is fine, upvote it since the question is tagged C#. But Googling "all loop iterations pass do action" or something similar will inevitably lead users to this question, and they might not be using C# :)

Comment: @Barry There is clearly a typo in my last comment... which I regret to be the case. It should read **Barry's answer is *not* C# specific**. I apologize for the confusion!

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Similarly, saying "extract it to a method" doesn't help at all with *getting the code to work*, and there's hardly enough code here to require it. None of the other answers provide a *useful* extraction so calling this "the worst answer here" is harsh.

Comment: Can think like a Design pattern :D

Comment: Using boolean flags like that is downright disgusting. Do this is a couple more times in your project and you got yourself a side-effect driven mess nobody can maintain. Extract that into a method. "[Extract till you drop!](https://sites.google.com/site/unclebobconsultingllc/one-thing-extract-till-you-drop)"

Answer (score 94):

You could also use a simple LINQ query like this one:

```
if (Enumerable.Range(1, 20).All(b => i % b == 0))
    DoAction();
```

Answer (score 37):

How about just:

```
if (i % 232792560 == 0) {
    // do action
}
```

If you want to check that your number is divisible by lots of numbers, that's equivalent to checking if your number is divisible by the least common multiple of all of those numbers. In this case, that's 2<sup>4</sup>*3<sup>2</sup>*5*7*11*13*17*19.

Comment: Make sure to leave a comment where that number comes from when you use this. This is by far the best answer though.

Comment: @Sumurai8 I wrote out the prime factorization. Insufficient?

Comment: @Barry I think he meant "leave a comment in the real source code", not leave a comment here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I believe this doesn't answer the question. This solves the problem posed by the example but the actual question is about the general situation where you have multiple conditions and want to act out on all of them. If I were to come in here thinking "great, have a bunch of checks to do, how can I simplify this", then your answer is going to be useless to me. Were the question "how to check if a number is divisible by lots of numbers", you'd be on point.

Comment: @Vld There is no general answer to the problem of having multiple checks. Generally, you have to check all of them. In this case, it's just easy to do all these checks either with LINQ or just combining them into a single check. So yes, I am answering the specific question.

Comment: Magic number... please no.

Comment: @Barry sure, you've solved the problem of every single person who comes in here to know if a number is a divisible by 2-20. Not the whole demographic, mind, you but only those of them who specifically googled their problem by using "action in a loop" (or similar) as a search term. While those people would probably be grateful, I think they will be a minority of the total amount of people coming in for an advice.

Comment: @Vld Look, if you don't think this answer is as helpful as others, just downvote it and upvote the ones that you think are helpful.

Comment: @Barry why can't I _also_ comment? Comments are here for a reason. If you don't feel like they are useful, you are free to disregard them, and that's it.

Comment: This has the best performance and the worst readability. I'd wrap the whole thing in a `DivisibleByAllUpTo20` function and call it a day.

Comment: Barry, your answer is superb, but I cant help but think you would be a nightmare to live with :(

Answer (score 25):

So you want to chain a number of very similar boolean expressions without writing them all explicitly.

```
if ((i % 1 == 0) && (i % 2 == 0) && (...) && (i % 20 == 0))
{
    do action x
}
```

The first thing you could do is to extract the combined expression used in the `if` statement into a new function. This makes your code more readable.

```
public static void Main()
{
    // ...

    if (DivisibleByAllUpTo20(i))
    {
        //do action x
    }

    // ...
}

private static bool DivisibleByAllUpTo20(int i)
{
    return (i % 1 == 0) && (i % 2 == 0) && (...) && (i % 20 == 0);
}
```

`DivisibleByAllUpTo20()` can then be implemented with a `for` loop like you tried.

```
private static bool DivisibleByAllUpTo20(int i)
{
    for (int b = 1; b < 21; b++)
    {
        if (i % b != 0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

By the way: the LINQ namespace provides lots of helper methods that lets you write such code much more concisely and cleaner:

```
using System.Linq;

// ...

if (Enumerable.Range(1, 20).All(n => n % i == 0))
{
    // do action x
}
```

Comment: This is the most complete answer; it shows the OP how to do it the way the they intended but couldn't quite finish, but also introduces them and future readers to LINQ.

Answer (score 11):

Easy:

```
bool isDividable = true;
for(int b=1; b<21; b++)
{
     if (i % b != 0)
     {
         isDividable = false;
         break;
     }
}

if(isDividable) do something
```

Comment: Jeez...  You were only 38 seconds later than the accepted answer (now with tons more votes), but IMO yours is better than the first iteration of the top answer because `flag` isn't descriptive.

Answer (score 5):

```
bool flag = true;
for(int b=1; b < 21 && (flag &= (i % b == 0)) ; b++)
    ;
if(flag)
   do_action();//do your task
```

Comment: @HimBromBeere If writing for the Obsfuscated C# Code Contest, then sure. Otherwise, typically code like this will just irritate anyone else who ever has to understand or maintain it. I'm not saying it's not technically clever or valid, but such tricks usually don't last long in sustainable codebases, for good reason... especially in a higher-level language like C# (i.e. I might understand ths more in C) where far better ways of expressing intent are available. Even if one added the missing comments, this would be less self-documenting than writing explicitly or calling a good library function.

Comment: I agree the &= is maybe a bit unnecessary to have inside the for statement like that and could be moved to the body to avoid irritating some people who are allergic to convoluted logic. Still by far the best answer to this question. Literally 10s of times better than all the crazy iffers in fors.

Answer (score 3):

```
bool action = true;
for(int b=1;b<21;b++)
{
     if (i % b != 0)
           {
               action = false;
               break;
           } 
}
```

After this:

```
if (action)
{
// do your action 
}
```

Hope it helped.:)

Answer (score 3):

You could write it like this

```
bool doAction = true;
for(int b=1;b<21;b++)
{
  if (!(i % b == 0))
    {
      doAction = false;
    } 
}
if (doAction)
{
  do action x;
}
```

That sets the bool to false when one condition is false, so it only executes `do action x;` when all conditions are true.

You could also do it in less lines with Linq:

```
var divisors = Enumerable.Range(1, 20);
if(divisors.All(div => i % div == 0))
{
  //do someting
}
```

Explanation: Enumerable.Range returns an Array with values 1 to 20 and the .All checks the Lambda expression for each object.

Comment: By not `break`ing, this makes the program pointlessly carry out all subsquent iterations even after the condition it exists to ascertain is proven false. That is bad for both performance and semantics.

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few similar answers here that use a flag. A simpler solution is to use the loop variable (`b` in your question) as the condition to test:

```
int b;
int max = 20;

for (b = 1; b <= max && i % b == 0; ++b) ;

if (b > max) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: This requires anyone reading the code to go WTF and mentally execute the code to figure out what it's trying to do. It's not at all clear that the loop does anything useful, _what_ that is, and what `if b > max` (is that even syntactically valid without parentheses?) _means_ for the given input. If answers using flags or, better, LINQ are so much more numerous - I think there's a reason. And sure, you could add comments explaining, but the best comment is no comment, rather to use code that doesn't require any.

Comment: @underscore_d This answer demonstrates a looping technique, and it is a useful skill to have in one's toolbox. There is an [entire site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) dedicated to discussions about code clarity and style, and although your attempt at elucidation may seem helpful, unfortunately you're just polluting so many comment chains here. I do appreciate the comment about missing parentheses though, I've been writing a lot of Swift code lately where they aren't necessary--I've edited my answer to add them in.

Comment: I've only made comments on 4 posts here. Only 2 can be subjectively accused of "pollution", which is up for debate, but not today. The other 2 point out objective waste/sloppiness in the code, i.e. not using `break` once an answer is found, continuing to loop for no reason. What am I missing? Do you have concerns ranging outside this thread that you'd like to discuss? Anyway, you're welcome for the parentheses.

Comment: Sigh. Tilt your windmills, friend.

Comment: Also,  you got it backwards: `// do something` executes if the condition is not met.